# Set Array formula output to variable vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an array formula that identifies the row number based on multiple criteria, however, I would like to set this value as a variable because I would like to use this as the row number for a different formula.

```
{=MATCH(J1013&"*"&"55",Workings!K:K&Workings!G:G,0)}
```

Any ideas how to save the output of this formula as a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Evaluate` method to evaluate a formula string and output it to a variable in VBA. For example:

```
Dim vRow
vRow = activesheet.evaluate("MATCH(J1013&""*""&""55"",Workings!K:K&Workings!G:G,0)")
```

Comment: nice, I will try this!

Answer (score 1):

To store intermediate results in formula calculations, you have two options:

1- Add a name in the name manager. i.e

```
Formulas ---> Name Manager ---> New... 
give it a name, such as myVariable and write the formula in the RefersTo box
```

This creates the variable, you can then refer to it in any formula, like:

```
= myVar*10
```

2- dedicate a cell to calculate the formula and refer to the cell.

Option-1 has the advantage of keeping this behind the scenes. Option-2 is more flexible when you want to do the calculation for a whole column, so that the intermediate must be different for each row. In this case, you put your intermediate results in what is called a *"helper column"*.

Comment: I chose to put the output into a cell, then saved that to a variable. Worked, pity there's no nicer way to do this.

Comment: @Lowpar I understand, we all wish Excel formula language had a way to reference intermediate results within the same formula. Well, it doesn't, but it's still an excellent tool :)